# Error building tensorflow for java with openJDK 10.0.1 and bazel on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, tensorflow, bazel

I was able to successfully build and use TensorFlow on Ubuntu 18.04 with Bazel and openJDK 10.0.1, but when I attempt to build the TensorFlow Java libraries I get the following errors:

> ERROR: missing input file '@local_jdk//:jre/lib/resources.jar'
>   ERROR: /home/kim/tensorflow/tensorflow/java/BUILD:20:1:
>   //tensorflow/java:tensorflow: missing input file '@local_jdk//:jre/lib/resources.jar'
>   ERROR: /home/kim/tensorflow/tensorflow/java/BUILD:20:1 1 input file(s) do not exist

Comment: What Bazel version are you using?

Comment: Bazel version is 0.16.0.

Comment: After spending too much time researching this problem, I gave in and installed JDK 8 as an alternative JVM and was able to successfully build TF for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK 8 and set the `JAVA_HOME` envvar.